# Delete two physical tables and insert those to separate two temp tables at once using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-delete

I'm having a SQL query which deletes records from a physical tables (header, line) and insert those records to a 2 separate temp table using `OUTPUT DELETED.*`.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[PartnerFilteredLines] 
OUTPUT DELETED.*
INTO @PartnerFilteredLines 
WHERE SettingsFileId=@SettingsSplitId

DELETE FROM [dbo].[PartnerFilteredHeader] 
OUTPUT DELETED.*
INTO @PartnerFilteredHeader 
WHERE SettingsFileId=@SettingsSplitId
```

Both 2 queries are working independently. My requirement is to somehow merge those 2 queries and do the delete part at one time (one execution) because for a development requirement this query is scheduled for 1 second. Therefore, sometimes `@PartnerFilteredLines` records are there and `@PartnerFilteredHeader` are not because they were executed in 2 executions.
Can somebody help me to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you want a cascading delete foreign key instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transactions to hold lock for table `PartnerFilteredHeader`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  -- lock table "PartnerFilteredHeader" till end of transaction
  SELECT ...
  FROM PartnerFilteredHeader
  WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[PartnerFilteredLines] 
  OUTPUT DELETED.*
  INTO @PartnerFilteredLines 
  WHERE SettingsFileId=@SettingsSplitId
    
  DELETE FROM [dbo].[PartnerFilteredHeader] 
  OUTPUT DELETED.*
  INTO @PartnerFilteredHeader 
  WHERE SettingsFileId=@SettingsSplitId


  -- release lock
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Hi @Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu thank you for your answer. One thing, do I  need to do this put this part WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK) in my query in order to lock the transaction. Because the first thing that I'm doing in my query is those 2 delete and insert to temp table parts.

Comment: you dont need it for delete statements. just I used on select to lock second table so that there wont be any change on it while you are deleting on first table

Comment: @ Derviş Kayımbaşıoğlu I just need to use BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION keywords before and after the DELETE queries right ?

Comment: you need to use SELECT query as well for locking second table.  Which means you need to use everything I mentioned in my answer